# ANTLR4 can't parse Integer if a parser rules has an own numeric literal

Tags: parsing, antlr, grammar, antlr4

I am struggling a bit with trying to define integers in my grammar.

Let's say I have this small grammar:

```
grammar Hello;
r  : 'hello' INTEGER; 
INTEGER : [0-9]+ ;
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

If I then type in

```
hello 5
```

it parses correctly.

However, if I have an additional parser rule (even if it's unused) which defines a token '5',
then I can't parse the previous example anymore.

So this grammar:

```
grammar Hello;
r  : 'hello' INTEGER;
unusedRule: 'hi' '5';
INTEGER : [0-9]+ ;
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

with

```
hello 5
```

won't parse anymore. It gives me the following error:

```
Hello::r:1:6: mismatched input '5' expecting INTEGER
```

How is that possible and how can I work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define a parser rule like

```
unusedRule: 'hi' '5';
```

Antlr creates implicit lexer tokens for the subterms. Since they are automatically created in the lexer, you have no control over where the sit in the precedence evaluation of Lexer rules.

Consequently, the best policy is to *never* use literals in parser rules; always explicitly define your tokens.

Comment: Thanks for your help! What would that mean for my grammar, would I have a lexer rule for every number (ONE, TWO, THREE, ...) and then build upon that?